# Doubts about google sites and HTML

Tags: html, google-sites

I have some troubles with google sites and HTML...I'd like to remind you that

I've spent a lot of time looking for the solution of the issue but I didn't get anything. I'm working on a Google website and I'd like to have a box with some text inside and then in a corner of the box a button where you can click and automatically get the text copied into the clipboard. Is it possible to do it in a Google site?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Hello Robby. Thank you for your answer. It could be duplicated(I saw that post yesterday) but I didn't get anything...

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm working on a google website"? But anyway, it is possible to copy text to the clipboard, you'll need to use Javascript. However, copying is restriced in most browsers and difficult to implement universally, so I'd suggest using a library like [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Comment: @samiles Thanks Samile. I'm setting up a website using google-sites(I guess it's the name of it). I'll have a look on clipboard.js

Comment: I can not make it work...